# Thermald throttle unsupported CPU after certain temperature using coretemp

Tags: linux, configuration, temperature, sensors

I have a Samsung R519 notebook running Arch Linux 4.19.2. The CPU is an **Intel Pentium Dual T3400 (2.16GHz)**. The CPU often hits its thermal critical level and shuts down during heavy workloads. **Fan is fully operational and heatsink is in its place with new paste**. To combat this, I have installed thermald as well as ran the sensors-detect utility to generate the lm_sensors config. The lm_sensors service is active and, based on the config file, only loads the coretemp module.

```
HWMON_MODULES="coretemp"
```

Thermald fails to start with the following error:

```
$ sudo thermald --no-daemon --loglevel=debug
NO RAPL sysfs present 
10 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:f:d (6:15:13)
 Need Linux PowerCap sysfs 
failed to open /dev/acpi_thermal_rel 
failed to open /dev/acpi_thermal_rel 
TRT/ART read failed
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml"
error: could not parse file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml
Unsupported cpu model, use thermal-conf.xml file or run with --ignore-cpuid-check 
THD engine start failed
```

I have created the thermal-conf.xml file, but I don't seem to be able to configure it properly, and both the manpages for thermald and thermal-conf.xml as well as various examples on the web don't make it clear enough. I understand the basic XML structure of the file but I am unable to fill up all the necessary values myself as they seem badly explained or way too cryptic.

The following devices are present in `/sys/class/thermal`:

```
cooling_device0  cooling_device2  cooling_device4  thermal_zone1
cooling_device1  cooling_device3  thermal_zone0
```

both thermal_zone0 and 1 are of type `acpitz`. There are no controllable fan devices present so I rely on passive cooling methods. To my knowledge the **CPU doesn't support any of the new p-step functionality** present in newer ones.

The coretemp device is present at `/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon1/` and doesn't contain a `temp1*` entry with the highest core temp out of the two. `temp2*` and `temp3*` are available and list their independent temperatures.

To finally get to my intention: I'd like to create a thermal-conf.xml configuration that has a thermal zone taking its values from coretemp. Upon reaching a certain temperature, for example 90000 (90C), thermald should attempt to engage passive cooling methods supported by the CPU and throttle it down.

Comment: I would advise detailing what you have accomplished and narrowing down the scope of the last request.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I haven't accomplished much other than what I listed so far. I've researched some paths and created a few configurations with "bogus" values to get the service to run, and it does. It simply doesn't get the values from the specified places nor does it do any sort of throttling as far as I'm aware.